# Add row totaling specified rows in r

Tags: r, janitor

I have the following problem (abstracted for simplicity).

```
w <- c('1st' , '2nd' , '3rd')
x <- c(1 , 2 , 5)
y <- c(50 , 17 , 22)
z <- c(55 , 20 , 14)
t <- data.frame(w , x, y , z)
t
    w x  y  z
1 1st 1 50 55
2 2nd 2 17 20
3 3rd 5 22 14
```

I would like to add a last row, "NewVal" , with the 3rd row less the 2nd row, i.e.,

NewVal , 3 , 5 , -6

There are several columns in the actual case so I would like to refer to columns w:z rather than individually. Janitor's adorn_totals looked promising but apparently you cannot specify the rows to be added. I tried tidyverse's add_row with an attempt to refer to the values I wanted to sum by indexing, but couldn't get that to work. I'm most familiar with tidyverse packages and syntax, and some functions of janitor, so a solution along those lines would be most helpful, but if that's not possible, anything would help. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
t %>%
  add_row(
    {.} %>% # helpful edit to avoid repeating `t`
      mutate(across(x:z, ~. - lag(.))) %>%
      slice(3) %>%
      mutate(w = "dif")
  )


    w x  y  z
1 1st 1 50 55
2 2nd 2 17 20
3 3rd 5 22 14
4 dif 3  5 -6
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you could avoid repeating `t`

Comment: How would you do it, use the magrittr T pipe?

Comment: Try to replace the second one with a dot `.`

Comment: Thank you, this is a clever and concise solution and will solve my problem. I like how the the data is manipulated by slice within the add_row function.

Comment: My suggestion does not work

Comment: To eliminate the need to refer to t again, or to do the operation after other procedures alter the original dataset, enclose "." in curly braces:

Comment: t %>%
  add_row(
    {.} %>%
      mutate(across(x:z, ~. - lag(.))) %>%
      slice(3) %>%
      mutate(w = "dif"))

Comment: @David It does not work

Comment: @Julien, I just ran the code again and it works for me. Here is the code with returns.

Comment: Sorry, I will post this as an answer below so the code is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
w <- c('1st' , '2nd' , '3rd')
x <- c(1 , 2 , 5)
y <- c(50 , 17 , 22)
z <- c(55 , 20 , 14)
t <- data.frame(w , x, y , z)
t

t %>% 
  add_row( {.} %>% 
             mutate(across(x:z, ~. - lag(.))) 
           %>% slice(3) 
           %>% mutate(w = "dif"))
```